# Proof that an integral with parameter is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, definite-integrals

Let $T > 0$ with $T \ll 1$ and $p(t), \lambda(t)$ defined by
$$p(t) = \frac{-|\ln(T)|}{\ln(T - t)^2} \quad \text{and} \quad \lambda(t) = \frac{-|\ln(T)|(T - t)}{\ln(T - t)^2}, \quad t \in [-T, T].$$
Let us define
$$E(t) = \int_{-T}^{t - \lambda(t)^2} \frac{p(s)}{t - s} ds.$$
I would like to know if this function is  increasing or decreasing (or neither). By taking the derivative of $E$, we get
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}E(t) &= \frac{p(t - \lambda^2(t))}{\lambda^2(t)}\frac{d}{dt}\left(t - \lambda(t)^2\right) - \int_{-T}^{t - \lambda(t)^2}\frac{p(s)}{(t - s)^2} ds\\
&=\underbrace{\frac{p(t - \lambda^2(t))}{\lambda^2(t)}}_{\equiv A}\underbrace{\left(1 - 2\lambda(t)\frac{2 -\ln(T - t)}{\ln(T - t)^3}\right)}_{\equiv B} \underbrace{- \int_{-T}^{t - \lambda(t)^2}\frac{p(s)}{(t - s)^2} ds}_{\equiv C}.
\end{align}
Clearly, by definition of $p$, $A$ is negative and goes to $-\infty$ for $T \to 0$ as $\lambda^2(t) \to 0$. Moreover, we can see that $B$ is positive as well as $C$. I struggle a lot to compare $AB$ and $C$. Intuitively, I think that by taking $T$ small enough, $AB$ will be extremely negative and therefore $AB + C < 0$ for every $t \in [-T, T]$. However, as the form of $C$ is rather complicated, I haven't been able to sketch its behavior, and (maybe), if I take $T$ really small, $C$ will go to infinity quicker than $AB$. Could one of you help me with this?